# is it haram to write about god replying to me like he did moses

Tags: practical-islam, sharia, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis

I'm writing a book/essay about solving mathematical problems. I write about praying and Allah replying, is this haram? I know for sure that writing about seeing him, or depicting him is wrong but I'm not sure about him replying. Is it mockery to make it like a dream? I've looked it up but can't find an answer.

Comment: it is unbecoming of God to speak to a human except as He pleases. There are very few instances in recorded human history where Allah has a direct conversation with a human being (Adam, Noah, Abraham, Moses, Mohammed). In most other cases, the Prophets have been given revelation through Angel Gabriel.  Only you know for sure if you have had a conversation with God or was it a figment of you imagination. Just remember, to make a false claim w.r.t God is considered a sin. May Allah guide us all to the straight path.

Answer (score 1):

In general, we can talk about answers we receive in prayer. However, this has to be true at least to our own understanding and consciousness.  Telling an invented story about a response is abuse and haram because it is a misuse of the name of Allah.
There may be a cause to write about our personal experience in prayer but a publication on math problems is for sure not supposed to include this.

Comment: ... and before anyone really writes something, he should at least have asked Allah before and be sure of His positive answer.

Comment: it is in my case, and thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see the connection between 'solving mathematical problems' and 'praying'. It's a non-sequitur: it doesn't follow. And nor do I see the point of writing something merely for someone not to follow. That's generally not the point of writing.

Any depiction of Allah, as you point out is haram. This includes turning Him into a figment of your imagination or dream. It is also haram to compare yourself to Moses or any other prophet.

Comment: the point isn't for you to see the connection, but nonetheless, thanks for your response

Comment: @muslimboyz123: You are not making sense. The point of posting to a public site is so others can understand.